# What are the key advantages and disadvantages of NDP compared to ARP?

Tags: ip, ipv6, arp, network-discovery, ndp

So why they didn't use ARP in IPv6? is there any real benefit of doing this?

what are the key advantages and disadvantages of using NDP instead of ARP? (In overall network performance, Security and etc)

For example if we had a IPv6 network, why not use ARP in that network instead of NDP?

Comment: NDP does a lot more than ARP ever did, and works on more types of links. RFC 4861 section 3 would be a good read.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Michael Hampton points out, ND does a great deal more than IPv4 ARP, but I will answer from the perspective of simply resolving a layer-2 address from a layer-3 address (ARP function).

ARP broadcasts requests to every host on the LAN, and that interrupts every host on the LAN to inspect and process the request to see if it is for them.

IPv6 has eliminated broadcast (a good thing). Instead, each interface must subscribe to a solicited-node multicast group for each IPv6 address assigned to the interface (each IPv6 interface will probably have at least two IPv6 addresses, and maybe more) based on the addresses assigned to the interface. When ND tries to perform an "ARP" function, it sends the request to the solicited-node multicast address (based on the IPv6 address to resolve). That will probably interrupt only the target host (far fewer hosts than IPv4 ARP).